# JQuery addclass to another div (but not parent) if no data is found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this to add a class to the main table that the report is in if there is no data returned.

`$('#report-area table td:contains("Sorry, your search did not return any data")').parents('#report-area').addClass('no-report-data')`

However, I have another div area `"#report-footer"` but it's not inside `#report-area`. I'd like to also add the `.no-report-data` class to `"#report-footer"` as well but in this case I don't think the `.parents` selector will work. Is there another selector I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID attributes are unique per-page so you can just say this:

```
$('#report-footer').addClass('no-report-data');
```

You could also skip the `parents` altogether and do them both at once:

```
if($('#report-area table td:contains("Sorry, your search did not return any data")').length)
    $('#report-area, #report-footer').addClass('no-report-data');
```

Comment: I like this one, it works fine. Note I had an error, it should always be "#report-area" and not '#reportArea', I've corrected my code above.

Comment: @Danny: Your question uses both `#report-area` and `#reportArea`, is the `#reportArea` a typo? If yes then we should fix them in both places to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Danny: Cool, I fixed the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Reference link http://visualjquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might work

```
var uglySelector = 'table td:contains("Sorry, your search did not return any data")';
$('#reportArea:has(#report-area ' + uglySelector +'), #report-footer ' + uglySelector).addClass('no-report-data');
```

I recommend you to avoid that long creepy selector ("table td:contains..."), when you write the message "Sorry..." message, just add a class to that td to distinct it later.

Comment: One of the issues is these tables are coming from JSP Jasper reports and the code generated is pretty bad. I don't have access to any templates and the tables have no id's or classes to begin with so I was forced to add classes based on text strings.  I know it's pretty nasty that way but I was given yucky code.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah, that things happens. Hope that my snippet works.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?  It's not real sexy, but should work....

```
var $noData = $('#report-area table td:contains("Sorry, your search did not return any data")').parents('#reportArea');

if ($noData.length)
{
  $noData.addClass('no-report-data');
  $("#report-footer").addClass('no-report-data');
}
```